# Does logrotate handle wildcards the same as ls?

Tags: logrotate

I'd like to specify the files for `logrotate` to handle via the following wildcard string: `/home/deploy/*/logs/nginx-*.log`

If I do `ls` with this wildcard string, it shows exactly the files I want to be rotated. Will `logrotate` handle the wildcard string as expected, i.e. the same as with `ls`?

Comment: Yes I believe it does!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does see `man logrotate`, but note the **warning**:

> Please use wildcards with caution.  If you specify *, logrotate will rotate all files, including previously rotated
>          ones.  A way around this is to use the olddir directive or a more exact wildcard (such as *.log).